# How to add setAdditionalFilters in DiscoveryClient when DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs is removed from there in latest Spring Cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, upgrade, service-discovery

Thanks in Advance for you answers.

I am upgrading spring cloud, i earlier had a bean to add additional filter as below

```
 @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean(DiscoveryClient.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs.class)
  public DiscoveryClient.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs discoveryClientOptionalArgs() {
    List<ClientFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add(new ClientFilterAdapter(jwtAuthRequestDecorator()));
    DiscoveryClient.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs args =
        new DiscoveryClient.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs();
    args.setAdditionalFilters(filters);
    return args;
  }
```

In the newer version of DiscoveryClient, DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs is removed/deprecated. could you please help me with another way to implement the same?

jwtAuthRequestDecorator is nothing but a bean to add additional header

```
public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add(TOKEN, jwtToken);
    return httpHeaders;
  }
```

i added implementation("com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.19.4") to include jersey client which is removed from spring cloud.

Comment: Jersey 1 uses javax.* Which spring Framework 6 and spring boot 3 are not compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding customized `RestTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs`:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs discoveryClientOptionalArgs(HeaderHttpRequestInterceptor headerInterceptor) throws Exception {
  RestTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs args = new RestTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs(new CustomEurekaClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier(headerInterceptor));
  return args;
}
```